# jQuery - Find top parent before div (parent of a parent of a parent...)

Tags: jquery

My question title was a bit vague, I honestly couldn't think of anything less confusing, sorry!

**Here's what I want:**

1. Find the first anchor inside top level div.
2. Find the top parent of the anchor BEFORE the above div.
3. Sorry if this is still confusing.

**Example:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="thisShouldBeIgnored"></div>
    <div id="ignoreThisToo"></div>
    <div id="one">
        <div id="two">
            <div id="three">
                <a href="" class="anchor">Hello</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to be returned here is the div with the id of `one`.

Here's what I'm doing, I'm using .html as an example.

```
var firstAnchor = $('#container a')[0],
    parentId = $(firstAnchor).parent().attr('id');

$(firstAnchor).html(parentId);
```

This currently returns `three` which I expect.

The next step is where I'm struggling.  How do I continue to get the parent until I hit that top level div, in this example `container`.

In short, I want to target the first anchor inside `container` and then get the top level parent before `container` which is `one`.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

**Here's a fiddle of what I have so far:**
http://jsfiddle.net/uk6oocs7/

Comment: are the id's dynamic? Becasue if you know it's always going to be one you can just .closest( "#one")

Comment: You won't have to rewrap in `$(...)` if instead of the `[0]` you use `eq(0)`.

Comment: Hi @ajmajmajma The only thing here that doesn't change is the `container` ID.  I'm working with other peoples code so the child ID's are always different.  But I'll always want the div that is being represented by `one`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, however it seems like you want to traverse upward until you hit a div with a (maybe you mean class not ID?), then find the first anchor tag within any of its children. Is this what you want?

Comment: .first will work for you then

Answer (score 4):

This should get it:

```
$('#container div').has('a').first()
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uk6oocs7/5/)**

This will select all the divs that are children of #container that have a child anchor element, and then reduce that to the first match.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this would do what you're looking for:

```
var parentId = $('#container a').parentsUntil('#container').last().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [`parentsUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) function in jQuery:

> Description: Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object.

So that would be:

```js
var firstAnchor = $('#container').find('a').first(),
  penultimateContainer = firstAnchor.parentsUntil('#container').last();

firstAnchor.html(penultimateContainer[0].id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="thisShouldBeIgnored"></div>
  <div id="ignoreThisToo"></div>
  <div id="one">
    <div id="two">
      <div id="three">
        <a href="" class="anchor">Hello</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle, this will do the trick:

```
var firstAnchor = $('#container a')[0],
    parentId = $(firstAnchor).parentsUntil('#container').last().attr('id');

$(firstAnchor).html(parentId);
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk6oocs7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the root's id, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uk6oocs7/9/).

```
var $firstAnchor = $('a.anchor:first'),
    ignoreLevels = 1 + 2, // on jsFiddle include html, body
    index = $firstAnchor.parents().length - 1 - ignoreLevels,
    parentId = $firstAnchor.parents().eq(index).attr('id');

$firstAnchor.html("ID: " + parentId);
```